# Amazon CodeDeploy ApplicationStop script fails no matter what

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, bitbucket, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to do auto deployment from bitbucket to an ec2 instance using codedeploy but Codedeploy always fails on "ApplicationStop" phase.

Here is my appspec.yml

`version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /quickdeal.zip
    destination: /home/ubuntu/quickdeal/
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/install_dependencies.sh
      runas: root
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts/stop_server.sh
      runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/start_server.sh
      runas: root`

and following is the stop_server.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# stop any old running servers 
killall -s KILL node -q || echo 'no node process was running'
```

But this is the error I get in aws

```
Error CodeScriptFailed
Script Namescripts/stop_server.sh
MessageScript at specified location: scripts/stop_server.sh run as user root failed with exit code 1
Log TailLifecycleEvent - ApplicationStop
Script - scripts/stop_server.sh
```

Things I have already tried

[1] Deleted and re-created the application 
[2] Emptied stop_server.sh so that it doesn't give out any exit codes at all (still got exit code 1)

Comment: Since you have two problems, you should really have two separate SO questions. I'm going to edit your question to remove problem #2 and then I'll try to answer your first issue.

Answer (score 1):

First off, when I try the `killall` command you have, it fails with:

```
killall: unknown signal q; valid signals:
HUP INT QUIT ILL TRAP ABRT EMT FPE KILL BUS SEGV SYS PIPE ALRM TERM URG STOP
TSTP CONT CHLD TTIN TTOU IO XCPU XFSZ VTALRM PROF WINCH INFO USR1 USR2
```

As to the issue you discuss, I'm pretty confident is that `scripts/stop_server.sh` is not an executable. If the script is not executable, you'd get something like `sudo: scripts/stop_server.sh: command not found` if you tried to run it manually. Try to run the script locally, and I bet you'll see that.

It's an easy fix though. Run this on any executables that you'll be running in your appspec - `sudo chmod +x scripts/stop_server.sh`, and that should solve your issue when you create your new application bundle.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and they were all executable to begin with. I checked the permission many times.
Someone else also faced those issues and suggested to clear the "/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root" directory & recreate code deploy app and it worked.

Comment: Hmm, weird. For your last successful deployment (before all of the failures), did you have a bug in `scripts/stop_server.sh`? When you do a deployment, it will actually use the `ApplicationStop` from your last successful deployment, not your current deployment. It's a common issue when the `ApplicationStop` scripts have a bug. You try to update the deployment and it continues to fail. If that were the case, you [can ignore application stop failures.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-deployments.html#troubleshooting-deployments-lifecycle-event-failures)

Comment: Hey mate , thanks a lot for the link to guide. And I guess that might be the problem. It was deployed successfully 3 times , and after that it started to fail when I made some changes in the stop script. Even after changing it back to the original one, it was still failing. But as I learned, stop script runs before any other script. Well the last option for me was to re-create the app.